# How to get view count using youtube data api in javascript?

Tags: javascript, view, youtube-data-api

I was trying to get some data using Youtube data api -v3. All the data inside data.items.snippet is coming perfectly. But, rest of the data, for example data.items[0].statistics.viewCount cannot be retrieve. Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

  var key = 'MY_API_KEY';
  var playlistId = 'PL6Oh0ejUo_0jJlgikR5CNH38O9NE5JDbK';
  var URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems';

  var options = {
      part: 'snippet,statistics',
      key: key,
      maxResults: 20,
      playlistId: playlistId
  }

  loadVids();

  function loadVids() {
      $.getJSON(URL, options, function (data) {
          var id = data.items[0].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
          mainVid(id);
          resultsLoop(data);
      });
  }

  function mainVid(id,c) {
      $('#video').html(`
        <iframe width="420" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      `);
  }


  function resultsLoop(data) {

      $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
          var c = item.contentDetails.duration;

          var thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
          var title = item.snippet.title;
          var desc = item.snippet.description.substring(0, 120);
          var vid = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;


          $('main').append(`
            <article class="item" data-key="${vid}">

              <img src="${thumb}" alt="" class="thumb">
              <div class="details">
                <h4>${title}</h4>
                <p>${desc}</p>
                                <p>${published_at}</p>
                                <p>${c}</p>
              </div>

            </article>
          `);
      });
  }

  // CLICK EVENT
  $('main').on('click', 'article', function () {
      var id = $(this).attr('data-key');
      mainVid(id);
  });

});
</script>
```

At first ***part: 'snippet,statistics',*** this part was like ***part: 'snippet',***

Comment: Seems statistics is not valid part in Playlist query [Please Refer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) and "statistics" supported video list query [Video api link] (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) .

Comment: Understood. So, it is possible to get list of video id from playlist and using those id, we can do one more code to get view counts of each videos, but is there any easier way to do that?

Comment: U can get list of video-id by using playlist api, then combine video ids and pass it to video api, "Mulitple video id" parameter supported in video api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally could solve it. The code is like the following one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var key = 'ENTER_YOUR_KEY';
  var playlistId = 'ENTER_YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID';
  var URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems';
    var URL2 = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos'

  var options = {
      part: 'snippet',
      key: key,
      maxResults: 20,
      playlistId: playlistId
  }

  loadVids();

  function loadVids() {
      $.getJSON(URL, options, function (data) {
          var id = data.items[0].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
          mainVid(id);
          resultsLoop(data);
      });
  }

//THIS FUNCTION WILL USE THE VIDEO ID FROM PREVIOUS API CALL AND RETRIEVE VIEW COUNT
      function view_count(vid) {
            var opt = {
                    part: 'statistics',
                    key: key,
                    id: vid,
            }
            var vc = null;

          $.getJSON(URL2, opt, function (data) {
              vc = data.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
                            $('#'+vid).append(`<p>Views: ${vc}</p>`);
          });
      }

  function mainVid(id) {
      $('#video').html(`
        <iframe width="420" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      `);
  }


  function resultsLoop(data) {

      $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {

          var thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
          var title = item.snippet.title;
          var desc = item.snippet.description.substring(0, 70);
          var vid = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
                    var view = view_count(vid); //CALL FOR VIEWS
                    console.log(view);


          $('main').append(`
            <article class="item" data-key="${vid}">

              <img src="${thumb}" alt="" class="thumb">
              <div class="details" id="${vid}">
                <b>${title}</b>
                <p>${desc}</p>
              </div>

            </article>
          `);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Get list of video-id by using **playlist api (V3)**, then combine video ids and pass it to video api, **"Mulitple video id" parameter supported in video api (V3)**

[Video Api Doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

List of use cases (mentioned in doc

1. list (by video ID)
2. list (multiple video IDs)
3. list (most popular videos)
4. list (my liked videos)